# C# check if something scan it

Tags: c#, .net, memory

Is there maybe a way to find out if a software is trying to scan my code or at least my software? I mean for example if cheat engine tries to scan for memory in my software written in C#. So I could prevent that scanning and close my application automatically.

I hope someone can help me or give me a hint.

Thank you very, very much in advance!

Comment: Are you asking whether its possible to be notified when another process is accessing the memory within your process? ...

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I'm looking for :). Would be so thankful for a solution or a hint :).

Comment: I wouldn't think so. It's possible to read the memory of another process - but I don't recall ever seeing an event or shell message that notifies of this.

Comment: Hm, at the moment I have the same mind. Is there maybe an method to check if another process just attached to my application? I already have a debuger protection but I want to protect my app from cheat engine and stuff like that too. By the way, thank you for your answer.

Comment: So you want to stop your program from running on any computer with a virus scanner installed? Good luck with that.

Comment: That is a little bit stupid. Who the hell want to code a virus which stops if it detects an anti virus system? Haha. That is just for the security of my software. Has nothing to do with that. And by the way ... it's easy to do that, just get all the names of the anti virus systems, check if it is running and shut your app down ...? I'm not a noob coder and I have better things to do than that.

Comment: @user3758768 I meant good luck finding a user that would turn off their virus scanner to run your n00b program.

Comment: Are you stupid or something like this? How do you know my software? And why the hell someone should turn of the anti virus scanner to run my software? Gosh, get a brain kid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe change the approach to the problem and instead ensure that the sensitive data is stored encrypted in memory, [`System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protectedmemory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

From above link:

> This class provides access to the Data Protection API (DPAPI) available in the Windows XP and later operating systems. This is a service that is provided by the operating system and does not require additional libraries. It provides encryption for sensitive data in memory.
>
> The class consists of two wrappers for the unmanaged DPAPI, Protect and Unprotect. These two methods can be used to encrypt and decrypt data in memory.

Answer (score 1):

There is Debugger class. You can check for debugging like this:

```
Debugger.IsAttached
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It only checks if the visual studio debugger is attached or not : /.